# Example about Picard-Lindelöf theorem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval, $x_0\in I$ and $\Omega\subset I\times \mathbb{R}$ such that $(x_0,y_0)\in \Omega$.

Picard-Lindelöf theorem states that the IVP

\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y), \quad y(x_0)=y_0
\end{equation}
where $f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function satisfying the Lipschitz condition on the variable $y$ has a unique solution in $(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta$) for some $\delta>0$.

**Problem: consider the IVP**

\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{\frac{y}{x-1}}, \quad y(x_0)=y_0
\end{equation}

determine the regions of the $xy$ plane for which there exists a unique solution of the IVP.

**What I have tried:**

Let $f(x,y)=\sqrt{\frac{y}{x-1}}$. Then $f(x,y)$ is continuous in the set of points $\lbrace(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x\geq 0, t>1 \text{ or } x\leq 0, t<-1\rbrace $. From Peanos' theorem I know that there exists at least one solution for the IVP in some of that regions.

In order to guarantee uniqueness I study the Lipschitz condition on $y$ of $f(x,y)$
\begin{equation}
\left|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)\right|\leq L \left|y_1-y_2\right|
\end{equation}
for some $L>0$. From the Mean Value Theorem we know that a differentiable function $f$ satisfying $\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|\leq c$ for some $c>0$ is Lipschitz in the variable $y$. For my problem I have
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x(t-1)}}
\end{equation}
which is continuous in $\lbrace (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x>0, t>1 \text{ or } x<0, t<-1 \rbrace$. Then I can found a unique solution of the IVP in any compact interval containing the initial condition in the regions where $\partial_y f$ is continuous.

My problem is that I've tried some examples which contradices what I've done here. For example, consider the initial condition $y(2) = 2$. Here $x_0 = y_0 = 2$ so from the Picard-Lindelöf theorem I can ensure that there exists a unique solution on a compact interval containing the point $(2,2)$. However I solved the IVP obtaining two solutions
\begin{equation}
y_1(x) = 2 \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right) \left(\sqrt{x-1}-1\right)+x, \quad y_2(x) = 2 \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)
   \left(\sqrt{x-1}-1\right)+x
\end{equation}
Obviously $y_1(x)=y_2(x)= 2$ for $x=2$ but I can choose a closed circle centered at $(2,2)$ and radius $R=\frac{1}{2}$ containing both solutions so solution is not unique. I don't know where i'm wrong :(

Comment: Separation and integration gives $\sqrt y=\sqrt{x-1}+C$. Inserting $y(2)=2$ gives $C=\sqrt2-1$. After squaring $y(x)=x-1+2(\sqrt2-1)\sqrt{x-1}+2-2\sqrt2+1$, which is your $y_2$. I do not see how you could get to $y_1$.